# Oracle Missing Comma error on check constraint

Tags: oracle, constraint, errors, check-constraints

I'm attempting to create a table in Oracle, but keep getting the "ORA-00917":missing comma error at the end of my first constraint (P_IMAGEFILE_CHECK). I've tried adding and taking away commas but nothing has worked, and I do not see how the statement is incorrect. Any suggestions?

```
CREATE TABLE P_SPECIES (
GENUS                         VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)         NOT NULL,
SPECIES                       VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)         NOT NULL,
COMMONNAME                    VARCHAR2(80 BYTE)         NULL,
SPECIES_DESC                  VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE)       NULL,
SPECIES_IMAGEFILE             VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)         DEFAULT 'NOIMAGE.JPG' NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT                    P_IMAGEFILE_CHECK         CHECK
              (REGEXP_LIKE(SPECIES_IMAGEFILE(UPPER('[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+.JPG')))),
CONSTRAINT          P_SPECIES_COMMONNAME_UK1            UNIQUE(COMMONNAME),
CONSTRAINT          P_SPECIES_PK                        PRIMARY KEY(GENUS, SPECIES),
CONSTRAINT          P_SPECIES_FK1                       FOREIGN KEY(GENUS)
              REFERENCES P_GENUS(GENUS)

);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your `regexp_like` expression that is invalid. You're using your column as if it was a function name. The syntax is:

```
regexp_like(thing_to_check, pattern [, options])
```

You should write:

```
regexp_like(species_imagefile, '[A-Z0-9._%-]+.JPG', 'i')
```

`'i'` is for case-insensitive matching.